# How to use webpack.config in karma.conf without duplication

Tags: karma-runner, webpack

I would like to `require` the webpack.config in karma.conf to reduce duplication. Somehow it is not working and some errors are being thrown.

`Module not found: Error: a dependency to an entry point is not allowed`
`ERROR [karma]: Uncaught ReferenceError: webpackJsonp is not defined`

the way `webpack.config` is required in `karma.conf`

```
var webpackConfig = require('./webpack.config');
webpackConfig.devtool = 'inline-source-map';
webpackConfig.plugins.push(new RewirePlugin());
```

The `entry` and `output` property of the `webpack.config` are not needed in `karma.conf`, that might be messing with the setup. How can I get rid of it?
I have tried: `webpackConfig.entry = {};` which didn't succeed.

The problem could also be something else?

Would be very nice if you could point to an existing example or correct my mistake!

Comment: Consider this exerpt: https://gist.github.com/AndrewRevinsky/a9ea020953580cb8e384

Comment: Thanks @Andrevinsky that was exactly what I was looking for!